# How to Select from a database using a dynamic variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL 2008 database that is stored on the same instance, but this database is created by the user and name is stored in SQL table. How do I write a select statement using dynamic sql or is there a another way

So for example:

Main database - myDB
User database - userDB  (this is stored in a myDB.dbo.tblUserDatabase)
userDB has a table called tblUserReports

I want to write something like this in dynamic sql:

```
SELECT * FROM userDB.dbo.tblUserReports
```

So tried:

```
declare @dbUser varchar(50)
set @dbUser = (SELECT strDBName FROM myDB.dbo.tblUserDatabase)

SELECT * FROM @dbUser.dbo.tblUserReports
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this... dynamic sql can become unmanageable very quickly so be careful.

```
declare @dbUser varchar(50)
set @dbUser = (SELECT strDBName FROM myDB.dbo.tblUserDatabase)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbUser) + '.dbo.tblUserReports'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Use `QUOTENAME(@dbUser)` for a little added protection.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parameterise the table name.  You will have to use dynamic SQL in your client or stored procedures.  It's a very unusual thing to want to do so think long & hard about if this is a good design.  Maybe if you share what you are doing then you'll get some additional ideas as to how to approach your problem.